# How to convert private key to base64 format?

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, cryptography, base64

I have a private key with the below format. The private key is just for testing.
xprvA3bdZ5Dz3QFmyC6Y7tKeJahknnUZPgpw2Zhf7LNmZ1uLfJo2b557DpPBeBVW6Etbggpnd6VRUEWvKUj3NnBuU1MeWH8CY7eVTQ2yvZUXYSq

That is very likely in a Ethereum format. I need to convert it to a base64 format, in order to use it in signatures. (filecoin transaction need to base64 encoded format of privatekey)

For sending Filecoin transaction I need to use this method:

`transactionSignLotus(unSignedMessage, privatekey)`

```
## transactionSignLotus (support Lotus schema)

Sign a transaction and return a JSON string of the signed transaction which can then be sent to a lotus node.

Arguments:

* **transaction**: a filecoin transaction;
* **privatekey**: a private key (hexstring or buffer);
```

My privatekey doesn't work for this method. I think I need to convert to base64, but I used most of the ways for converting the private key to base64 format, cannot got results.

Note: When I say base64 I mean something like this:

```
px2g1zwEd1+EMfj4nX1oh0roouBGHhPo7QUNkPBHk1Q=
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'Ethereum format'?

Comment: transactionSignLotus needs this format * **privatekey**: a private key (hexstring or buffer);

Comment: @veedata The private key is generated by ethereun

Comment: @Topaco  key should be  * **privatekey**: a private key (hexstring or buffer);

Comment: actually this is [a Bitcoin format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0032#Serialization_format) shared by Ethereum @Topaco: which uses base58check -- base58 with 4 bytes truncated hash for redundancy added before encoding and removed after decoding. (Bitcoin's base58check also includes a tweak for leading zeros, but xprv and xpub values don't have leading zeros so that can be ignored.) And addresses in both Ethereum and Bitcoin are derived from publickey not privatekey.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat 68879302.js
let bip32 = require('bitcoinjs-lib').bip32
let x = bip32.fromBase58('xprvA3bdZ5Dz3QFmyC6Y7tKeJahknnUZPgpw2Zhf7LNmZ1uLfJo2b557DpPBeBVW6Etbggpnd6VRUEWvKUj3NnBuU1MeWH8CY7eVTQ2yvZUXYSq')
console.log(x.__D)
$ node 68879302.js
<Buffer cf 8c f7 64 cb d5 6b 5c 40 fa d6 7c 40 9d 52 2e c1 17 e4 93 16 dd 03 ec ec c4 1f 6c 80 6c ee d4>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import base64

key = b'xprvA3bdZ5Dz3QFmyC6Y7tKeJahknnUZPgpw2Zhf7LNmZ1uLfJo2b557DpPBeBVW6Etbggpnd6VRUEWvKUj3NnBuU1MeWH8CY7eVTQ2yvZUXYSq'

b64 = base64.b64encode(key)

print(b64)

# got b'eHBydkEzYmRaNUR6M1FGbXlDNlk3dEtlSmFoa25uVVpQZ3B3MlpoZjdMTm1aMXVMZkpvMmI1NTdEcFBCZUJWVzZFdGJnZ3BuZDZWUlVFV3ZLVWozTm5CdVUxTWVXSDhDWTdlVlRRMnl2WlVYWVNx'
```

Did it help?

Comment: I need the format something like this px2g1zwEd1+EMfj4nX1oh0roouBGHhPo7QUNkPBHk1Q=

Comment: It should be : * **privatekey**: a private key (hexstring or buffer);

Comment: Try using this: `b'heresyourkey'.hex()`

Comment: What is b? Because I'm using nodejs and it causes error.

Comment: It converts a string into bytes.

Comment: Got error, (node:4588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Base64 decode error | Invalid last symbol 49, offset 221.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use *nix with bash tools:
$> echo -n “* privatekey: PUT-YOUR-HEX-HERE” | base64 -w 0

Comment: I need do this programatically

Comment: Can you do in two steps: (1) create base64 string as shown above (2) hardcode to any var in js code and test request response. If you succeed - use base64encoder to encode the string in js.